# View.contains(x, y) doesn't work properly for 3x3 grid

Tags: java, android, mobile

I am building a game on a 3x3 grid, when the user hovers over the button it must log to the console what block they are on, but the way it is it registers the top blocks only due to the `y` value being the same.

here is the code:

```
if(b1R.contains(x, y)){
//          arr.add("1");
        Log.d("block", "1");
    } else if(b4R.contains(x,y)){
//          arr.add("4");
        Log.d("block", "4");
    } else if(b7R.contains(x,y)){
//          arr.add("7");
        Log.d("block", "7");
    }

    if(b2R.contains(x,y)){
//          arr.add("2");
        Log.d("block", "2");
    } else if(b8R.contains(x,y)){
//          arr.add("8");
        Log.d("block", "8");
    } else if(b5R.contains(x,y)){
//          arr.add("5");
        Log.d("block", "5");
    }

    if(b3R.contains(x,y)){
//          arr.add("3");
        Log.d("block", "3");
    } else if(b6R.contains(x,y)){
//          arr.add("6");
        Log.d("block", "6");
    } else if(b9R.contains(x,y)){
//          arr.add("9");
        Log.d("block", "9");
    }
```

The reason I have it in `if else if` statements like that is otherwise it logs all 3 blocks in the same column (1,4,7 or 2,5,8 or 3,6,9) all at the same time when I hover over 1 button.

The b1R stands for the button 1 rectangle, it is set up like this (b1 is image button 1 on the 33 grid):

```
b1R = new Rect(b1.getLeft(), b1.getTop(), b1.getRight(), b1.getBottom());
```

At the moment it is only returning 1 when I hover over the left column (any block in the left column) and the same for any column. How could I get passed this error / issue?

**UPDATE**

I have come to the conclusion that all the blocks are given the same coordinates, and I cannot figure out why...

here is the code:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus){
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if(hasFocus){
        Log.d("b1 left", ""+b1.getLeft());
        Log.d("b1 top", ""+b1.getTop());
        Log.d("b1 right", ""+b1.getRight());
        Log.d("b1 bottom", ""+b1.getBottom());

        Log.d("b2 left", ""+b2.getLeft());
        Log.d("b2 top", ""+b2.getTop());
        Log.d("b2 right", ""+b2.getRight());
        Log.d("b2 bottom", ""+b2.getBottom());

        Log.d("b3 left", ""+b3.getLeft());
        Log.d("b3 top", ""+b3.getTop());
        Log.d("b3 right", ""+b3.getRight());
        Log.d("b3 bottom", ""+b3.getBottom());

        Log.d("b4 left", ""+b4.getLeft());
        Log.d("b4 top", ""+b4.getTop());
        Log.d("b4 right", ""+b4.getRight());
        Log.d("b4 bottom", ""+b4.getBottom());

        Log.d("b5 left", ""+b5.getLeft());
        Log.d("b5 top", ""+b5.getTop());
        Log.d("b5 right", ""+b5.getRight());
        Log.d("b5 bottom", ""+b5.getBottom());

        Log.d("b6 left", ""+b6.getLeft());
        Log.d("b6 top", ""+b6.getTop());
        Log.d("b6 right", ""+b6.getRight());
        Log.d("b6 bottom", ""+b6.getBottom());

        Log.d("b7 left", ""+b7.getLeft());
        Log.d("b7 top", ""+b7.getTop());
        Log.d("b7 right", ""+b7.getRight());
        Log.d("b7 bottom", ""+b7.getBottom());

        Log.d("b8 left", ""+b8.getLeft());
        Log.d("b8 top", ""+b8.getTop());
        Log.d("b8 right", ""+b8.getRight());
        Log.d("b8 bottom", ""+b8.getBottom());

        Log.d("b9 left", ""+b9.getLeft());
        Log.d("b9 top", ""+b9.getTop());
        Log.d("b9 right", ""+b9.getRight());
        Log.d("b9 bottom", ""+b9.getBottom());

        b1R = new Rect(b1.getLeft(), b1.getTop(), b1.getRight(), b1.getBottom());
        b2R = new Rect(b2.getLeft(), b2.getTop(), b2.getRight(), b2.getBottom());
        b3R = new Rect(b3.getLeft(), b3.getTop(), b3.getRight(), b3.getBottom());
        b4R = new Rect(b4.getLeft(), b4.getTop(), b4.getRight(), b4.getBottom());
        b5R = new Rect(b5.getLeft(), b5.getTop(), b5.getRight(), b5.getBottom());
        b6R = new Rect(b6.getLeft(), b6.getTop(), b6.getRight(), b6.getBottom());
        b7R = new Rect(b7.getLeft(), b7.getTop(), b7.getRight(), b7.getBottom());
        b8R = new Rect(b8.getLeft(), b8.getTop(), b8.getRight(), b8.getBottom());
        b9R = new Rect(b9.getLeft(), b9.getTop(), b9.getRight(), b9.getBottom());
    }
}
```

Comment: "The reason I have it in if else if statements like that is otherwise it logs all 3 blocks in the same column (1,4,7 or 2,5,8 or 3,6,9) all at the same time when I hover over 1 button."
> This indicates that there is a bug in how you set up the rectangles or how you calculate if a co-ordinate is inside one. That should not be happening; no one point can be in all three rectangle areas unless they are overlapping, which they should not be, right? Are you sure everything is working in the same co-ordinate system? Are you sure no rectangles overlap?

Comment: Yes, it is in a table layout swell

Comment: What?
As a test, print out the top, bottom, left and right of each rectangle and make sure none overlap. Also print out the x and y mouse values you're testing. There should be no way for it to fall in multiple rectangles. Your if/else is the wrong approach.

Comment: Okay, I will do that. Why is the if else the wrong approach? what would be the right approach?

Comment: I printed out the variables, and it looks like all of them have the same coordinates - how can I fix this?

Comment: I had to manually add the height of the row, so the second row was `.getTop()+120` and the same for `.gotBottom()+120` and then for the last row it was `+240`

Comment: Here is a quick way to test if a `List<String>` with numbers called `s` (like `{"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"}` is equal to an `int` called `n` (like `123456789`): `java.util.Arrays.toString(s.toArray()).replaceAll("\\D", "").equals(Integer.toString(n))`.  Hope it helps :)